# Python - Xlwt more than 256 columns

Tags: python

I am importing text files into excel using xlwt module. But it allows only 256 columns to be stored. Are there any ways to solve this problem?

Answer (score 18):

`xlwt` supports creation of XLS files of the kind created by Excel 97-2003 and read by Excel 97 onwards. The file format is limited to 256 columns and 65536 rows. No amount of changing 256 to some other number in the `xlwt` source code will change that.

You have 3 options, in increasing order of complexity:

(1) as suggested by another, write a CSV file.

(2) [openpyxl](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/openpyxl) ... Excel 2007+ xlsx/xlsm format

(3) win32 COM (Windows only)

Comment: What worked for me  was a different version of option 2. I used xlswriter(https://pypi.python.org/pypi/XlsxWriter) instead because the code changes to shift to it (for me) were very few like workbook_name="testraw.xls" > workbook_name="testraw.xlsx", wb = xlwt.Workbook() > wb= xlsxwriter.Workbook(name) , ws = wb.add_sheet(sheet_name) > ws = wb.add_worksheet(sheet_name), wb.save(sheet_name+'.xlsx') > wb.close() . This might help someone to shift fast. As Excel 12 aka Excel 2007 introduced .xlsx and .xlsb which supports up to 1,048,576 rows by 16,384 columns. hence should do for most purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Line 8 in the file `Column.py` in the `xlwt` package sets the column limit to 256:

```
raise ValueError("column index (%r) not an int in range(256)" % colx)
```

You could change this number in the `xlwt` source to allow more columns, but this will break compatibility with older (**edit**: ALL) versions of excel.

**EDIT** The xlwt maintainer says that **this will not work**, so **don't try to do it** (I'll leave this answer here as I think it's useful to have the warning).

Comment: Wow, my first minus vote! Look at your error message (the one you've added to your answer) and fix line 76 in Row.py too. It's the same problem.

Comment: And not your last if you continue to carry on like a bashi-bazouk. There are three places to change. Not that that will help. Excel 2007 shrieks about unreadable data, attempts recovery, and fails miserably. Why TF do you think those error checks are in there? **A message from the xlwt maintainer: Don't do this. It is a waste of time and effort. Excel 2003, 2007 and 2010 will refuse to open the file.**

Answer (score 2):

use xlsxwriter and pandas.

```
import xlsxwriter, pandas

writer = pandas.ExcelWriter(file, engine='xlsxwriter')
pandas.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

Comment: The question is specifically asking about the `xlwt` module

Answer (score 1):

Is that a statement of fact or should xlwt support more than 256 columns? What error do you get? What does your code look like?

If it truly does have a 256 column limit, just write your data in a csv-file using the appropriate python module and import the file into Excel.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('..\output\The file.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter') 

file.to_excel(writer,'output_sheet') 

writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to write to the columns in the for loop and getting this error, then re-initalize the column to 0 while iterating.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30546712)