# Python Binary Matrix to Excel

Tags: python, excel, matrix

I'm trying to export a binary matrix to excel..
I'm using what I've learned from [Write list of lists to excel file using xlwt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25307848/write-list-of-lists-to-excel-file-using-xlwt)

and I'm getting an size error
well, I have a binary matrix 2221x9947 and the following code:

```
def wrapper(fn, *args, **kwargs):
    def wrapped():
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped

def int_to_str_matriz(matriz):
    for i in xrange(len(matriz)):
        for j in xrange(len(matriz[i])):
            matriz[i][j] = str(matriz[i][j])
    return matriz

def escreve_matriz_xml(rows, sheet):
    for i, row in enumerate(rows):
        for j, col in enumerate(row):
            sheet.write(i, j, col)

def exportar_matriz(matriz):
    book = xlwt.Workbook()
    name = "matrizbinaria.xls"
    sheet1 = book.add_sheet("teste", cell_overwrite_ok=True)
    exportar = wrapper(escreve_matriz_xml(matriz, sheet1))
    book.save(name)
    book.save(TemporaryFile())
```

I first use `mb = int_to_str_matriz(matriz)` to convert the *ints* on the matrix to *str*, then I pass the new matrix to `exportar_matriz(mb)`

I'm trying with this, and get

```
ValueError: column index(256) not an int in range(256)
```

and if I try the other option that it's given on the topic I quoted, using

```
def escreve_matriz_xml(rows, sheet):
    rows = [', '.join(row) for row in rows]
    for i, strrow in enumerate(rows):
        sheet.write(i, 0, strrow)
```

It works, the problem is that it is not useful this way, because I need to each column to have the (0,1), so I can analyze the data..
any solutions?
I tried without the str convertion and gets the same error...

Comment: your first error is a limitation in xlwt: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658513/python-xlwt-more-than-256-columns

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this using `xlwt`. Instead, consider exporting to `.csv` format (either using a library such as [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html), [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/), or [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/), or without the aid of a library).

The `.xls` (Excel 2003) file type is limited to 65536 rows and [256 columns](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/272729), so there is no way you can export your 2221 by 9947 matrix using `xlwt` (unless you transform it into a different shape first). This restriction was removed on later file types such as `.xlsx` (Excel 2007), but the `xlwt` library does not currently support this format.